# Delete mysql data after echod php

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to delete MySQL database data after it is echod once. I will not include all of my code since it worked fine there is no point in checking that part.

`$db = 'SELECT blah1, blah2, blah3 FROM dbtest LIMIT 1';`

Then after echoing everything out I tried to delete it using

`$sql = "DELETE FROM dbtest WHERE id='one of the row names go here?'";`

I'm not sure how to do this. In my database I have Email, Password and that's it.
What would go in place of the `id=`?

Comment: You have to use what you have so use `WHERE email='the last email address fetched'`

Comment: I would use the primary key, whatever column(s) that is(are)

Answer (score 0):

Extract a unique field e.g `id` for the one echoed and pass it to the query

```
// Say the last echoed entry has the id : $id, then

$sql = "DELETE FROM dbtest WHERE id=$id"
```

Comment: According to @Noah there is only an `Email` and `Password` field in his table so using `id` would not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have a table named as users and it has the fileds id, email and name.

```
$dataUser=mysql_query("select id,email,name From users LIMIT 1");
$result=mysql_fetch_array($dataUser);

echo $result['name'].' / '.$result['email'];

//Now lets delete:
if(mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id='".$result['id']."'"))
       echo 'row was deleted';
```

Now you can change id for email if it is the only field that you have as unique or index. But if you don't have an id field, I encourage you to create one, set it as index and auto increment.  I hope this can help you.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5 - http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php  You should move to the `mysqli_*` functions

Comment: It's only for pedagogical purpose. For him understand the way that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have the two fields in your table you would use the following:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `dbtest` WHERE `id` = '$emailAddress' LIMIT 1";
```

But...you need  to make sure you check `$emailAddress` before blindly using it in a query, especially one that deletes data.

Comment: Data storage is cheap, add a `isDeleted` column as a bool or similar (`tinyint` ?) and set it to true/1 instead of deleting.  Get fancy and add a time stamp as well, or make the deleted a timestamp, and you can eventually start really deleting things that were marked as deleted 6+ months ago or whatever is appropriate.